# Run-time error '1004' - Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Y"
Range("B1").Select

Dim lastcellex As String

Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

lastcellex = ActiveCell.Address
Range("B1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:lastcellex")
```

Can anyone help me as to why I keep getting this error? I set the variable to be equal to the last cell on the range but one column over. So if the range in column A was A55, lastcellex would be B55. I am trying to make it autofill from B1:B55.

Please let me know what you guys think.

Comment: One line: `Range("B1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row+1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:" & lastcellex)
```